# How to define a Compose Key in terminal (no desktop environment)?

Tags: console, keyboard-layout

I would like to define a `compose` key on my system (Debian Sid "Wheezy"). I have no Xorg (and don't want any desktop environment). Only in terminal.

I would like to set it up on my `Alt-Gr` key (right `Alt`). I've tried for a while but I can't figure out how to set it up.

I've been investigating and found some directions:

- `$ showkey` gives me the keycode of my `Alt-Gr` key (#100)
- `$ dumpkeys` and `$ dumpkeys --compose-only` output "the current contents of the keyboard's driver", in the format specified by `keymaps`, according to the `man` page
- `$ loadkeys` load a keyboard translation table

I'm sure it's not that difficult but I miss how to deal with that ...

Comment: Hm, I'm not following 100%, what would you like the Alt-Gr to do when you hit it?

Comment: I would like it to be the [Compose Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compose_key). Actually, I just would like to define a Compose Key somewhere, and since I'm used to have it on my Alt-Gr, I'd like to define it there. It's very easy to [set up with a GUI](http://stefaanlippens.net/sites/stefaanlippens.net/files/images/ComposeKey_options-edit.preview.png), but I should be able to define it in pure console mode since I have no X system installed (it's not an option). I just can't figure out how.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

On newer Debian and Ubuntu systems, your keyboard settings are put in `/etc/default/keyboard` and shared between X and the console.  Just run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and select `Compose key:` `Right Alt (AltGr)` on the appropriate screen.

You could also put `XKBOPTIONS=compose:ralt` in `/etc/default/keyboard` and run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

---

Older systems have a Compose key on the console by default.  In the `us` layout, pressing **both** <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys together acts like <kbd>Compose</kbd>.<sup>1</sup>

For example: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> => Ä

If you prefer <kbd>AltGr</kbd> only to be <kbd>Compose</kbd>, you need to change

```
alt keycode 100 = Compose
```

in your active keyboard map to

```
keycode 100 = Compose
```

The easiest way to do this is to make the above changes in `/lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/linux-with-alt-and-altgr.inc`.

A better way is to create a new file called `/lib/kbd/keymaps/i386/include/altgr-is-compose.inc` with the above line, create a new keymap that includes it, and set that to your default keymap.

1. <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> also acts as <kbd>Compose</kbd> by default.

Comment: I'm not getting this to work. The `dpkg-reconfigure` wizard indeed asks about a compose key, but it says it does not work in "Unicode mode" (?). Also, when not in that mode, it says Control + period works as a compose key. But I'm not getting that to work either.

Comment: I think that warning message refers to [`unicode_start`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unicode_start).  For me, it still works, provided I run `setupcon` as `dpkg-reconfigure` says.

Comment: When I run `setupcon` in my X terminal (`urxvt`), it says "We are not on the console, the console is left unconfigured." Also, `showkey` complains "Couldn't get a file descriptor to the console". In `tty`, both those works but `showkey` says (the first thing) that "kb mode was UNICODE", so perhaps that is indeed why it is not working. But, the Control + period works in `tty`. OK, it makes sense now.

Comment: Your question said you don't have `X`?  You need to run `setupcon` on the Linux virtual console, e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Comment: Right, like I said, it makes sense now. It wasn't my question, I just liked to try it out anyway.

Comment: Ok, sorry to spam this thread with my mistakes but I must say that I was wrong, it does work exactly as described, I didn't do `setupcon` as superuser. That whole Unicode stuff is apparently something else.

Comment: @cblab If my answer worked, please consider accepting it by clicking the check/tick mark.

Comment: Sorry for the delay for accepting your answer, I didn't forget you :o] I found that `dpkg-reconfigure` way by myself in the while, and it's working great, though, I'm still struggling on how to redefine the compose keymap (weird, but on debian sid, it doesn't seem to be a standard compose keymap, I mean, with mod+o+c, I don't get the ©, or with mod+.+c, don't get ċ ...).
But well, your answer definitely was well, and thank you then. Ah, just one thing, on my setup, the `PrtScr` key isn't defined as a Compose key, neither other ways you mentioned, but `Ctrl`+`.`, + combination instead

Comment: Looks like `console-setup` doesn't support very many compose sequences by default.  You can run `dumpkeys --compose-only` to see which ones.  You should be able to modify the `console-setup` init script to add additional compose rules where it runs `loadkeys`.

Comment: Yep thanks, I have seen the compose sequence allowed by default and indeed it's not a complete set as I wished, but I still have to investigate on how to define mine with `loadkeys` indeed. Thanks!

Comment: If this doesn't stick after a reboot, your system may be using IBus by default. Try running `dconf write /desktop/ibus/general/use-system-keyboard-layout true`

Answer (score 3):

"compose" on the console allows to type two characters but output a third one.

the problem is that the compose definitions use *bytes*, both as the two input (that is, you can't define compose in terms of typed keys but only in term of typed symbols) and for the output.

to make it work in UTF-8, which is multibyte (1 to 4 bytes, at least) would require great changes in the way console input is handled, and replace the simple char array currently used by something more complex. It seems there aren't plans to do so (the consensus among kernel devlopers is that console should remain a console, something simple, only used for last ressort; if you actually need unicode then you likely also need bidi, shaping, etc; then it is better to run a graphical terminal (an fullscreen xterm on X11; but there are other possibilities).

So, indeed it doesn't work, and won't work, with multibyte characters on console.
BUT, it still works if you restrict the compose definitions to plain ASCII.

And I also found out that it also works if the output is in iso-8859-1 (that correspond to unicode values up to 0x00ff); for that you can put in some start script a line:

```
    loadkeys /somepath/somefile
```

and put in that file the compose definitions you want (be careful to save the file in ISO-8859-1 encoding; and use chars bigger than 0x7f as the output only)
the syntax of such a file is very simple, lines like this:

```
    compose 'somechar' 'somotherchar' to 'desiredoutput'
```

eg:

```
    compose 'a' 'a' to 'å'
    compose 'a' 'e' to 'æ'
```

the apostrophe has to be escaped.

the effect of dead diacritics keys are also defined in that file; for dead_acute + a you define a line like:

```
    compose '\'' 'a' to 'á'
```

dead_grave uses backtick (`), dead_diaeresis uses doublequote ("), dead_circumflex uses circumflex (^) and dead_tilde uses tilde (~).

Comment: Thanks, got it to work. Only, I had to change `compose 'a' 'a' to 'å'` into `compose 'o' 'a' to U+00E5`, otherwise `loadkeys` complained about a syntax error.

Comment: when you used 'å', did you wrote the file in iso-8859-1 (not utf-8)?

Comment: I don't know. How do I check that?

Comment: to test if a file is in utf-8: `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 filename`  if no errors, it is in utf-8

Comment: That seem to cat the file, but no, there are no errors on `echo $?` at least, and no output to `stderr`. Also, `file` tells me it is UTF-8 so it makes sense.

Comment: and that was the problem with your "å"; the console compose file MUST be in an 8bit encoding only (as kernel uses *bytes* to handle that). if you convert it to iso-8859-1 then loadkeys will be happy (or, as you found out, using U+00xx notation (limited to 0+0001.U+00ff)

Comment: That's interesting: if a plain terminal doesn't support it, then how can I work i.e. with a directory/file with a name `→`? I can see it through `ls`, but can't type it.

Comment: [Checking in several years later](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/630879/why-is-the-behavior-of-the-compose-key-different-under-pure-console-and-x/631003#631003), there is no longer a limitation to single-byte characters. With Linux 5.4, both the composed characters and the resulting characters can be Unicode code points beyond 256.