# X follows keyboard layout toggle but console does not, crazily

Tags: debian, ubuntu, keyboard-layout, console

Two systems behave the same weird way, Xubuntu 20.04 and Debian 11 testing.

I've set the following in `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBOPTIONS="compose:caps,grp:win_space_toggle"
```

This works under X, but in the console Win+Space does nothing, and layout is instead toggled with Shift+Space, which I didn't request.

This is irritating as hell when I'm typing something like `cat asdf > qwer`, as layout unexpectedly changes in the middle.

Why is it suddenly Shift+Space and how to make it Win+Space, as I wanted?

**UPDATE**:
It's even more complicated than that. I experimented setting different values to `grp` in `/etc/default/keyboard`, seeking logic in how it's followed. After choosing each new value, I rebooted.

X follows the setting correctly.

Console not only NEVER sets the toggle to what I asked for, it actually demonstrates *different behavior for the same setting* throughout the experiments:

| X, following `grp` in `/etc/default/keyboard` | Console |
| --- | --- |
| Win+Space | Shift+Space **OR** Win |
| LCtrl+LShift | Shift+Space **OR** Win |
| LWin | LCtrl **OR** Shift+Space |

This looks more than crazy. Some changes don't make the console change its toggle. Some lead to a change, but surely not to what's requested. Like there are some values that console "prefers" and navigates through them in a stateful way.

Is this some kind of a weird bug or is it really a part of the design?

Where to dig further?

Comment: X doesn't control console, assuming you are using 'console' to mean, what you are in when you are out of X or Wayland. So what you want to do is stop barking up this wrong, tree, and figure out how to make console do what you want. I don't know the answer there, sorry, but you do want to stop paying attention to X configurations when you are clearly not wanting X configurations. It's two questions, you solved the first one, how to make X do what you want, now you have to solve the second one, how to make console do what you want. Kernel > shell/console > X > desktop/wm > term emulator.

Comment: @Lizardx I assume that under recent Debian-based distros making console do what one wants (in regards to keyboard settings) is exactly editing `/etc/default/keyboard`. Both X and console read settings from that file. I'm really surprised by *how* console reacts. By the way, the Compose key setting, also set in that file, is treated correctly by both X and console.

Comment: The 'X' is a dead giveaway that this is an X feature. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xorg/Keyboard_configuration https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xorg-docs/input/XKB-Config.html - I believe this is what you are looking for: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Linux_console/Keyboard_configuration - Arch tends towards good documentation. You'll note the config file /etc/vconsole.conf (at least in Arch). Usually when something is preceded by an X, like Xrandr, XKBOPTIONS, xdpyinfo, X11, X.org, it suggests it's something X uses. Which is above console level, not applicable.